# Fade in effect for new created elements

Tags: jquery, html, append, fadein

I know that there is a JQuery function name `fadeIn()` and have search some information how to used that. On [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp) I've read this:

> The jQuery `fadeIn()` method is used to fade in a **hidden element**.

But I'll use that function for elements that I've just created to fade in, it's not hidden! Is there a way to make the same effect for new created elements? Here is some code to play whit it:

```
$("#resultaatArtisten").append(
    '<div class="option-item">' +
        '<input type="hidden" value="' + var1 + '"/>' +
        '<div class="artist-foto-container">' +
            '<img src="' + image + '" class="artist-foto" alt="Foto van ' + name + '"/>' +
        '</div>'+
        '<p>' + name + '</p>' +
    '</div>'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#resultaatArtisten").hide().append(
    '<div class="option-item">' +
        '<input type="hidden" value="' + var1 + '"/>' +
        '<div class="artist-foto-container">' +
            '<img src="' + image + '" class="artist-foto" alt="Foto van ' + name + '"/>' +
        '</div>'+
        '<p>' + name + '</p>' +
    '</div>'
).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first `div` tag you could add `style="display:none"`, or you can add `display:none;` to your `.option-item` in your CSS file.

**Edit**

It is recommended that you add the `display` property into your CSS file.

`.option-item{display:none;}`

Comment: Oke sir, but I've already `display: flex;` added into my css class.

Comment: Set `display:none;` in your CSS file. Use the callback function from `.fadeIn()` to change the CSS property. For example `.fadeIn(500, function(){$('.option-item').css('display','flex')})`